# How can I build this typ of class interface

Tags: c++

I am interested in trying something where I create a custom type and then access to its members using dot semantics. For example:

```
 Class A{ //simplified, omitting constructors and other methods
   private:
   float numbers[3];
   public:
   float x(){ return numbers[0]; }
   float y(){ return numbers[1]; }
   float z(){ return numbers[2]; }
  }
```

So I can do something like this:

```
  A a;
  //do stuff to populate `numbers`

  float x=a.x;
```

But I would also like to make the elements in `numbers` lvalues so I can do something like this:

```
  A a;
  a.y=5; //assigns 5 to numbers[1]
```

How can I do this setting method?

Comment: What's wrong with `class A { public: float x, y, z; };`?

Comment: Becuase the actual size of `numbers` might vary; i will use a template to set its size

Comment: Then how will you know what names to use?

Comment: @BoBTFish I will set checks to make sure it is at least a size of 3 before it returns a value for `z`, for example. I appreciate your questions, but they are an aside to what I am actually asking.

Comment: Nope, now I think I know what the question actually is: Your class will contain an array, and you want three members `x`, `y` and `z` that refer to (probably the first) 3 elements of the array, correct?

Comment: As I stated earlier, the array might be a variable number depending on how the template is called, not necessarily 3 elements. If it were a fixed number, I could just make public members.

Comment: @Fellowshee if there are 14 elements will you have a, b, c, ... l, m, n, as attribute names?

Comment: @PeterWood this is a limit to now many I will need and the template will address that, but those details are secondary to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a reference to allow assignment:

```
float & x(){ return numbers[0]; }
      ^

// usage
A a;
a.x() = 42;
```

You should also have a `const` overload, to allow read-only access to a `const` object:

```
float x() const {return numbers[0];}
          ^^^^^

// usage
A const a = something();
float x = a.x();
```

Comment: Switching to this answer, in part thanks to your useful comments to others' answers which are important notes

Answer (score 1):

First. You made **functions** x, y and z but assigning them to float. This wouldn't work.
Second. Change these functions to return referencies:

```
class A{ //simplified, omitting constructors and other methods
   private:
   float numbers[3];
   public:
   float & x(){ return numbers[0]; }
   float & y(){ return numbers[1]; }
   float & z(){ return numbers[2]; }
};
...
A point;
float x = point.x();
point.x() = 42.0f;
```

There's another way: declare referencies as a members of class and initialize them in c-tor:

```
class A{ //simplified, omitting constructors and other methods
   private:
   float numbers[3];
   public:
   float & x;
   float & y;
   float & z;
   A() : x( numbers[ 0 ] ), y( numbers[ 1 ] ), z( numbers[ 2 ] ) {}
};
...
A point;
float x = point.x;
point.x = 42.0f;
```

P.S. Pay an attention on comment, that gave @MikeSeymour

Comment: Reference members aren't a good idea: they prevent the class from being assignable.

Comment: @MikeSeymour you're right, and I'd prefere the first method, but I don't know what OP wants and I gave two ways. Thank you for comment - I'll edit an answer to point on this moment

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you actually have public variables named x, y and z.

Or you can return a reference and then do `a.y() = 5`